# Force location update

Tags: iphone, timestamp, cllocation

I'm attempting to overcome a sometimes-failure of didUpdateToLocation when checking local data based on current position, closing the app, traveling a bit, and opening the app again. What happens is that the user visits one place, checks the list, goes to another place, and the list is updated but using the old location data.

I would like to make sure I have a fresh newLocation.

What's wrong with this code?

```
double aa,bb,cc;

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    [manager stopUpdatingLocation]; //only stop if new reliable pos fetched.
        //old data? retry.
    aa=[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    bb=[NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    cc=bb-aa;   //must be <60 - minute-fresh
    if (cc>60) {
        [manager stopUpdatingLocation]; //only stop if new reliable pos fetched.
        [manager startUpdatingLocation];    //only stop if new reliable pos fetched.
        return;
    }
...handle position
}
```

The symptoms are that cc is about 1200 seconds on app start, then on each retry it increases a few seconds.

I've tried `-[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow]`, and similarly it increases a few seconds at each retry. At one point the interval was ~2400.

I'm using FilterNone and AccuracyBest, if that could influence it.

I'm open to alternative code solutions to make sure you have a fresh position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was that you need to write the handling the way you want it to behave.

I've read up on this common problem. I should have clarified that "force" means *to start unambiguous behavior that gives a reliable position under optimal conditions* for the phone. Not to busy-wait until satisfied or to expect an immediate result/error code.

From a common sense viewpoint, what would be desirable by all developers would be at least an extra method to simply ask for a position within parameters, and callback only when it's valid and within accuracy, or canceled, or timed out. If the conditions prevent it you then don't need to test out esoteric behavior to be able to handle it with custom code.

Why I needed to ask about this at all was:

1. no existence of a method functioning as described above
2. using code from a book (More Iphone 3 Development)
3. when writing it from scratch (looking at LocateMe.xproj), discovering that:
4. simulator behavior differs from phone behavior (not talking about the position itself, which is obviously as good as ip lookup can make it, but the behavior of didUpdateToLocation). Recognizing the limitations of a simulator, the method should at least behave like they do on a device. But currently, correctly written location handling/checking code just times out in the simulator (as in the LocateMe example), while incorrect code (asking once and using newLocation on callback) works.
5. and a bug causing didUpdateToLocation being called twice after [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

If on top of this you (like I) load data based on your position, and the data is required by multiple views in your application, the behavior of Apple's location-fetching methods doesn't make it easy to handle the chain of update-load-calculate-present consistently and problem-free throughout the app. Especially if your stuck between user/boss perception or decision of how it should work (a rock) and how the system works (a hard place).

**Here's my current code which works on a device and in a simulator:**

```
//ask for a position, as fresh as possible.
-(void)updateMeMap {
    lastloc.coordinate=homeloc.coordinate;
    lm.delegate=self;
    ctr=0;
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopUpd) withObject:nil afterDelay:gpstimeout];
    [lm startUpdatingLocation];
}

//called on each position update.
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    ctr++;
    if (ctr<15) {
        NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
        NSLog(@"%d",ctr);
        if (locationAge<60) {
            NSLog(@"Found");
            ctr=40;
            homeloc.coordinate=newLocation.coordinate;
            [self stopUpd];
            [self reload];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Lastupd");
            lastloc.coordinate=newLocation.coordinate;
        }
    } else {
            //enough tries, if not canceled choose lastloc.
        if (ctr<40) {
            NSLog(@"Last");
            ctr=40;
            homeloc.coordinate=lastloc.coordinate;  
            [self stopUpd];
            [self reload];
        }
    }
}

//force stop updates. ctr prevents extra calls after stopUpdatingLocation.
//called after the timeout delay, if position found, cancel the timeout.
-(void)stopUpd {
    [lm stopUpdatingLocation];
    lm.delegate=nil;
    if (ctr<15) {
        ctr=40; //2 extra calls after stopupda... otherwise, now do nothing.
        NSLog(@"Timeout");
        homeloc.coordinate=lastloc.coordinate;  //@need "copy"?
        [self reload];
    } else {
        ctr=40; //2 extra calls after stopupda... otherwise, now do nothing.
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(stopUpd) object:nil];
    }
}

    // "couldn't get userlocation" handler. I also cancel like this on connectionDidFailWithError.
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Location failed: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    ctr=0;
    [self stopUpd];
}
```

Where ctr is there to prevent the 2 extra calls, lastloc is last known reliable position, homeloc is the phone position used for (threaded) loading of location-specific data with [self reload].

The constants 15 and 60 are safe values from real-world testing; gpstimeout is set to 30. If you work a lot in a simulator you may want to set it to something short like 3 seconds, as all you will get is a stale but relatively usable position and no more until the timeout.

Edit: If you can best my code or point out an omission, I'll mark that as answer, I hate marking my own as answer.

Comment: NOTE: While this is code based on current behavior of CLLocationManager and you should be aware that behavior might change, it works reliably with no error reports for months. So right now this is a trusted solution for all our apps and I will mark this as the answer. The real answer is of course that it isn't possible to force a location update, but this code is a good enough substitute.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across a similar problem in one of my previous apps.

There's no way to force a location update as far as I'm concerned - (I searched for a long time and didn't find anything)

One thing that I found was using the `UIBackgroundModes` key in my info.plist.

Support for some types of background execution must be declared in advance by the application that uses them. An application declares this support by including the UIBackgroundModes key in its Info.plist file. Its value is an array that contains one or more strings with the following values:

- audio. The application plays audible content to the user while in the
  background. (This includes streaming audio or video content using
  AirPlay.)
- **`location`. The application keeps users informed of their
  location, even while running in the background.**
- voip. The application
  provides the ability for the user to make phone calls using an
  Internet connection.

Which is what you're looking for. See the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I'll ask if that's a viable option.

Comment: The problem is that this is an app that is used a couple of times a day, hours apart. Now, when the app is closed in between it isn't shut down, or it wouldn't be a problem - I'd just ask for an update on start. But if I were to check location continuously in the background, the app would use up battery unnecessarily for hours or days while doing nothing like navigating or show anything useful; it would never stop. So, refresh on app resume. The expected behavior is to get your new user position and present local data.

Comment: Usually this is in a city, so no problem. Except I must still try my darndest to get a fresh, valid position before I dare present the data. If the data is wrong, the user is confused or reports an error or thinks the app is crap. I realize try is all I can do, and for navigation on a map it's familiar to the user; you just wait a little a see the dot move to the right place. For a list or such it's not that obvious, and so I had to battle the "try" behavior (and Apple bugs) with handling code to get an acceptable presentation behavior; you can't shuffle/replace data like you can move a dot.

Comment: I would suggest you to only update the location in the background using following methods of cour `CLLocationManager`:

`-(void)startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges;`

`-(void)stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges;`

These can be used to increase battery life greatly - The Manning Book `iOS 4 in Action` covers exactly this topic in chapter 21 and chapter 22

Comment: Thanks, still, this is not optimal for a "navigate once a day and sometimes once a week" app, so I didn't get an ok for a background GPS update solution.

Answer (score 1):

What if you put more of the code within the age check, like:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (locationAge<60) {
        [manager stopUpdatingLocation]; //only stop if new reliable pos fetched.
     ...handle position
    }
}
```